# what is the best query_cache_size / Ram ratio

Tags: mysql, performance, ubuntu, caching, ram

hi I want to change my /etc/my.cnf file (mysql's config file).

What should the below values for better performance on my queries.

```
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 16M
```

Is there an optimal ratio for cache_size / RAM ? I have 8GB of ram on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: You measure the use of your database and adjust the cache accordingly. There is no "best" value. If there were, MySQL would ship with it by default.

Answer (score 11):

If there were a well-defined optimum there would be no need for a configuration option. MySQL would use that optimum by default. The [query cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html) is also only useful for very specific circumstances (you read a lot more from the table than you write to it) because the cache is emptied on a per-table basis every time you write anything to the table. It also only works if you state the exact same queries, with the same parameters, over and over.

The optimal value for you needs to be measured out and depends a lot on your use case. If you have a lot of InnoDB tables you will get much more use out of the [InnoDB buffer pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html): `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Set this variable as high as possible (and on a MySQL-only, InnoDB-only machine this might mean as much as 80% of your available RAM).

We host hundreds of small websites on our 8GB RAM server, which runs both database and web server on the same machien, with a mixture of MyISAM and InnoDB tables. Here is our configuration for comparison:

```
innodb_file_per_table=1
open_files_limit=50000
max_allowed_packet=268435456

innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_io_capacity=1000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=5000

key_buffer_size=16M
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_limit=5M
join_buffer_size=4M
sort_buffer_size=4M
max_heap_table_size=64M
tmp_table_size=64M
table_open_cache=4500
table_definition_cache=4000
thread_cache_size=50
```

Comment: So if we have RAM = 64G can we multiply the each value with 8 ? Will the be good to do on production server ?

Comment: No, there is not one set of settings that will work for everybody. You will have to measure your workload and figure out what works best for you.

Optimally you would run only MySQL on the server. Then you should focus on setting innodb_buffer_pool_size as large as possible. If I had a 64GB server that runs only MySQL I would set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 62 GB or something like that.

My example was for a server that also needs RAM to other things such as a web server.

Answer (score 5):

If your machine has a lot of writes, turn the Query cache completely off (type=0, size=0).  That is because *every* write to a table causes *all* entries in the QC for that table to be removed.

As a corollary to that, having too big a QC can be "slow".  I recommend no more than 50M for query_cache_size.

I hope that explains why I did not address your title question about percent of RAM.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the size of the query results. If you have a query cache limit of 5M and query_cache_size of 256M a worst case scenario will let you end up with 55 query results of 5M in your cache.

Depending on the type of queries you run most you are better of setting a smaller query_cache_limit (**64k**) giving you a total of **4096** smaller query results in the cache. On top of this the results in the cache are smaller and will not lock the query cache longer then needed.

The query cache of MySQL uses a single thread that locks the cache on every request. If to many requests connect to the query cache the overall performance will drop.

Answer (score 1):

[Note](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html)

> The query cache is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.20, and is removed in MySQL 8.0.

So the query cache in MySQL is nothing to build your future on.